# CollectionView ReloadItems Issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So, I have a collectionView, with a custom cell. Inside the cell is a view, which backgroundColor depends on a firebase observer notification.

I'm setting the 'collectionView cellForItem' like so:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = self.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell

    cell.user = users[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Inside my custom cell, I'm setting the user as so:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {

        guard let status = user?.online else { return }

        activeIndicator.backgroundColor = status ? UIColor.green : UIColor.lightGray
    }
}
```

In my viewController, I have a function that observes changes at a Firebase node. Specifically, a boolean value.

```
private func observeChanges() {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userReference = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    /** Notification: Update local users **/
    userReference.observe(.childChanged) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        let user = User(dictionary: dictionary)

        if snapshot.key != uid {

            if user.online ?? false {

                for (index, value) in self.users.enumerated() {
                    if value.username?.contains(find: user.username ?? "") ?? false {
                        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
                        self.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that value is 'true', I want to reload the indexPath as shown. This intern, updates the backgroundColor of my view, inside the associated cell.

It doesn't work, however. Any ideas

Comment: You need to update `self.users` with the new `user` object.

Comment: I thought by reloading the item, the status would have changed from the observe notification and that would 'update' it. How would I update it otherwise?

Comment: I print the array of users and their associated 'online' status, and the array is updated.

Comment: I don’t see any code where you update the array and the behaviour of your cell indicates that you haven’t either

Comment: Ahhh, a complete mishap on my part. This simply was the fix.
users[index].online = true